# Read a sentence to make a dictionary or array or list of keywords/keyphrases

Tags: c#, algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

This is the problem, say we have a sentence like this:

> one or more time

The Sentence is split on the basis of space .

The idea is to make a a dictionary or array or list whatever suitable, out of the above which would contain all the words unique and increasing order which would be either a keyword or keyphrase. 
So i should get something like this:

```
one 
or 
more 
time
one or 
one or more 
one or more time
more time
...etc so on
```

But these are not:

```
time more 
or time 
one time
more or
etc
```

This is what i tried:

```
private void AddWordsInDictionary(string phrase, ref Dictionary<string, string> dctKeywords)
{
    var keyWords = phrase.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(x => x.Trim() != string.Empty).ToList();

    foreach (var keyword in keyWords)
    {
        if(!dctKeywords.ContainsKey(keyword))
        {
            foreach (var key in dctKeywords)
            {
                dctKeywords.Add(key + " " + keyword, key + " " + keyword);
            }
        }
        else
            AddWordsInDictionary(keyword, ref dctKeywords);
    }

}
```

But it keeps returning a blank dictionary also i do not know if algorithm is optimal, please help.

Comment: You don't need this for loop : foreach (var key in dctKeywords). You start with dctKeywords being empty so the code never gets into the for loop and nothing is ever added.

Comment: Okay, then how do i generate the keywords?

Comment: Remember to always check MSDN documentation to verify whether your assumptions are correct or false! Look at the inner foreach loop: `foreach (var key in dctKeywords)`. What is `foreach` doing? It iterates over a collection or enumerable sequence like IEnumerable<T> or ICollection<T>. What kind of collection is *Dictionary<TKey,TValue>*? Remember, i said to check the MSDN documentation ;) There's perhaps more wrong in your code, so this is just a starting point here...

Comment: Can someone `PLEASE` help me find a solution rather than lecturing?

Comment: If you only look for a coding service, then you are at the wrong place here. But that's just my opinion. Others might perhaps be eager to do your work for you...

Comment: You already have a for loop :  foreach (var keyword in keyWords).  You do not need two for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
private static void AddWordsInDictionary(string phrase, ref Dictionary<string, string> dctKeywords)
{

    var keyWords = phrase.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(x => x.Trim() != string.Empty).ToList();

    Dictionary<string, string> dct = new Dictionary<string ,string>();
    int id = 0;

    string newPhrase = "";
    foreach (var keyword in keyWords)
    {
        dct[id.ToString()] = keyword;
        newPhrase = newPhrase + id.ToString();
        id++;
    }

    int xx = 0;

    while (xx < newPhrase.Length)
    {
        for (int idx = 0; idx <= newPhrase.Length; idx++)
        {
            if ( idx - xx > 0)
            {
                var item = newPhrase.Substring(xx, idx - xx).ToString();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var itm in item)
                {
                    sb.Append(dct[itm.ToString()] + " ");
                }
                var key = sb.ToString().Trim();
                dctKeywords[key] = key;
            }
        }
        xx++;
    }

}
```